# Lambert function - Need help finding an analytical solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

I am working with my homework, where I am asked to solve an equation and provide the answer analytically.
$$e^{1-3x}-x=0$$
I can get an numerical solution ($x\approx0.54$) but I am really struggling with the analytical solution. I am starting to believe that this equation can't be solved analytically but in am not sure. If the Lambert function can be applied, how can I manipulate the equation in order to get an answer?

In advance thanks!

Comment: Google for **Lambert function** which is simple and beautiful !

Comment: the solution is given by $$x=\frac{1}{3} W(3 e)$$

Comment: Hei @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I have taken a look to the Lambert function and I understand that I can manipulate the feuqation in order to get $a =be^b$ and then multiply/take $W$ in both sides. Could you show me what did you do to the equation in order to get the result you did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{1-3x}-x=0$$
$$e^{1-3x}=x$$
$$1=xe^{3x-1}$$
$$3e=3xe^{3x}$$
Since the RHS is now in the form $ze^z$, we can apply the Lambert W:
$$W(3e)=3x$$
$$x=\frac{W(3e)}3=0.539214\dots$$

Comment: Thank you @Parcly I appreciate your answer! I have learn something new today! :) Math is awesome!

Comment: It is worth to note that 
since the argument of $W$ is positive,
there is only one real solution.